# Prevent overlapping of transparent background with opaque background

Tags: css, background-image

I have a `div` and i want to give it 3 backgrounds. Background image of left and right is transparent but because my center background image is `repeat-x`, the center background goes under left and right backgrounds, is there any way to stop this event?

```
div {
    background: url('images/left_nav_bg.png'), 
                url('images/right_nav_bg.png'),
                url('images/center_nav_bg.png');

    background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat,repeat-x;
    background-position: left,right;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to achieve. Would making opaque background in `left_nav_bg.png` and `right_nav_bg.png` solve your problem?

Comment: Do you know up front how wide the left and right background images are?

Answer (score 0):

To only show the center background between certain points you would have to give it a start and a stop offset, and at the moment you can only set one of the two. I'm afraid you'll have to work with a pseudo-element for the center image:

```css
div {
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/45/300),
                url(http://placekitten.com/37/300);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left, right;
    
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}

div:before {
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/17/300) top left repeat-x;
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 37px;
    z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<div> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </div>
```

The `left` and `right` position the center background so that it doesn't overlap the other two.

The `position: absolute` and `z-index: -1` make sure the center image doesn't overlap the contents in the `<div>`.